# C# Sort List<T> by its property which is string of datetime

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a List every item of that list is user defined class which has a property which type is string but its content is datetime, like the following;

StringAsDate="23/10/2020 17:12:00"

class Unknown{
...,
StringAsDate,
...
}

list of T list

I want to sort the list descending which is string that container DateTime, i have to preserve the format of list at the end.

I can do that by brute force but im looking for efficient and elegant way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments on the answers you are looking for a reflection based solution.

The reflection part, to get the value of a property based on the name:

```
x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null)
```

Try this:

```
var propetyName = "StringAsDate";
var listSorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null))));
```

If the `Property` is already of type `DateTime` a cast would be sufficient

```
var propetyName = "StringAsDate";
var listSorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => (DateTime)x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
List<UnKnown> listSorted = list.OrderByDescending(x=>DateTime.Parse(x.StringAsDate));
```

Comment: You have a typo, it's `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: thats good but actually we can access the name of the field as string so we have to access the field by its name, i mean i have a string value which is the name of the field so i cant access it directly

Answer (score 0):

`List<Uknown> list` = example for your list containing the objects.

```
List<Uknown> sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTimeParse(x.StringAsDate));
```

Comment: thats good but actually we can access the name of the field as string so we have to access the field by its name, i mean i have a string value which is the name of the field so i cant access it directly

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of `object`.

```
List<object> sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(d.GetType().GetField("StringAsDate").GetValue(d).ToString())));
```

With this your code will work with any class as long as they have this field.

But in case you have control on the Classes being sent to your collection I would suggest that you implement an interface on all the Classes `ITimeStamp`
and then

```
   List<ITimeStamp> sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.StringAsDate));
```